# Find all polygons in an image programmatically

Tags: color, patterns, raster

I'm looking for a way to programmatically find all polygons on a drawing surface, and identify them by colour. They will all have one out of a known set of colours.

Something like the coloured blobs on the women's face, only I will only be using the layer with the blobs:

This is not a design mode scenario. It is dealing with the images while they are displayed in an application.

[image]

Comment: eh... Could you give us a bit more? In what software, what kind of image? Do you have an example screenshot?

Comment: I will be using only the layer of the PNG with the coloured blobs. I want to find all the coloured blobs. They will actually be polygons.

Comment: I see. I'm still not too sure what it is you're asking, but that might be just me :). What is the result you'd want?

Comment: And if you are using Illustrator there's Select Similar Objects at the top. Same for me it's unclear wether you use a Photoshop (bitmap) or Illustrator (vector) file.

Comment: @Vincent, on the image above, the coloured blobs over her mouth and eyes are on a separate layer. Looking only at that layer, I want to find those, and any other, blobs, and then plygonise them.

Answer (score 2):

This question's vague, but if you're using Photoshop the Color Sampler Tool may be what you need.

Accessible underneath the eyedropper tool, it looks like this: 
[image: color sampler]

You can  click specific points on your document, like say the blobs on your example image:

[image: color samples]

And in the info panel the point's color values will be displayed:

[image: values]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great idea, and I could use several graphics apps to do this, but I have amended my question to clarify that I want to do this programmatically.